# align an element to the bottom of window

Tags: css

I am trying to use jQuery to calculate the window height then apply that value to a DIV (the container div) finally i want the jQuery to align an element to the bottom of the page.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="element-align">Here is the element i wish to align to the bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting this element to remain at the bottom of the window even when the page is scrolled down? If so this can be done in CSS.

Comment: yes that is correct ! @Roy McCrossan

Comment: Just a suggestion. Whatch out doing codez : resize window issues. And a Q: CSS is not quite good?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Further to my question on your OP, this can be done in CSS:

```
#element-align {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If needs be you can also add left/right to the element, but the fixed positioning will mean that the element will always appear in the same place relative to the browser chrome, regardless of the scroll position of the page.

Comment: Issues: Do NOT forget our dearest ie6 and the position fixed bottom:0px. Do not even forget about mobile Safari.

Comment: Thanks mate, i added a min-height:100%; and height:auto; to the container for this to work fully. :)