# Make site footer stick to bottom of the page or below content depending on the height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On [my site](http://jcubic.pl) I want to have the footer stick to the bottom of the page if the content is smaller than the window height or on a large screen (I can do that with position:absolute). If the content is larger (that's how it is now) I want it to sit below my content. I know how to do it that way but don't know how to mix the two.

How can I do this? Do I need to use JavaScript or can it be done with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it.
You can have a look at this links:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: I can't make it work on my page, even if the content is smaller then the window I've got scrollbar and the footer is not visible when scrollTop is 0.

Comment: There will be then some other css rules breaking the layout. The best thing I would suggest is start with a prototype from scratch (I use to play with colored divs to better simulate the different areas).

Comment: Ok, I fix it, the wrapper (I add section) need to have only one element inside.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Footer stays at bottom when content is less:

### [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/39ZjP/2/)

**2.** Footer goes below content when content exceeds screen/window height:

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/39ZjP/3/)

**CSS**

```
html,body,#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#container{
    display:table;
}
#content{
    display:table-row;
    height:100%;
}
#footer{
    min-height:45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some already asked a similar question the answer is in CCS, I hope this helps.

```
#element-align {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See link bellow for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029162/3324507

Comment: Is wrong answer because if content will be larger then the height of the window the fitter will be in the bottom of the window not the page (so it can show up in the middle of the page).

Comment: This isn't what the original poster asked for. He wants it to sit at the bottom until the height of he content grows to a sufficient size to push it down. Position fixed will simply stay at the bottom regardless of the content size.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question completely. Sorry guys