# Align element to bottom of window

Tags: css, footer, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to display `footer` element always aligned to the bottom of the window, regardless of the content of page.

The behaviour should be the following:

- when window is large and content doesn't fill all the available space, footer should be aligned at the bottom of the window (not attached to content)
- when window is narrow and content overflows, footer should be attached to the bottom border of the content and a vertical scrollbar relative to (header+content+footer) height should be displayed
- footer height should not be fixed, but it depends on footer content

I've found this tricky [**snippet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029102/align-an-element-to-the-bottom-of-window)

```
#element-align {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but I don't think it's proper in my case: when I resize window, footer height changes and I can't compensate it with a `padding-bottom` value on content. If height exceeds padding, content is hidden under footer. Here's my current [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/utg0sbv1/3/).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How would you like it to behave? Scrollbar on the content, not the entire page?

Comment: Hi @AustinBrunkhorst. Scrollbar should be on entire page. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: So... I don't really see what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that when I resize window, the last part of the content is hidden under the footer.

Comment: So that means you *would* like the scrollbar on the content, not entire page. Think about it, where is the content supposed to go? The page is not tall enough.

Comment: I would like that page height = headerHeight + contentHeight + footerHeight. The scrollbar behaviour is exactly this: jsfiddle.net/utg0sbv1/8 The difference is that when window is large and content doesn't fullfill height, footer mustn't be attached to content, but kept at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the trick!

Basing on [LcSalazar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410174/align-element-to-bottom-of-window/25410633#25410633), I've created a table layout.

```
html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    display:table;
}

header,footer {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-row;
}

.content {
    display:table-row;
    background:lightgreen;
    height:100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2u5wsa0b/)

By setting content `height:100%;`, when window is large content fills all the available space and pushes header to top and content to bottom.

Ok, someone could claim it's not exactly the OP because `header` is no longer fixed positioned. But I think it's a good start point in that case too... without javascript! :-)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

They key here is that the footer **must** be a part of the flow of the document just in case #content is taller than the viewport. Use `#content { min-height: 100% }` to push the footer down to the bottom of the page, using padding and negative margins to make room for the header/footer.

The only downside is you need to know the height of header and footer, and if their height is variable then you need to use javascript. But it is still lightweight.

If you know they height of header/footer then you can hardcode these values.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/utg0sbv1/9/

HTML

```
<header>Header content</header>
<section id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas molestie condimentum condimentum. In id interdum lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis semper venenatis bibendum. Suspendisse id tellus quis sapien malesuada ornare. Proin non dui vel dui placerat bibendum. Donec euismod, nisl sed vulputate fringilla, dolor arcu condimentum enim, rutrum luctus mi tortor id velit. Praesent hendrerit, odio a aliquam vestibulum, orci purus placerat mi, vel facilisis libero orci sit amet purus. Pellentesque quam sem, iaculis eu sem in, suscipit pulvinar libero. Duis vulputate sollicitudin dolor nec lobortis. Cras tempus, sapien at vestibulum semper, elit lectus viverra metus, id adipiscing mi orci a odio. Proin pulvinar et nisl vitae faucibus. Integer pretium, tortor sit amet aliquet feugiat, lacus lectus facilisis ligula, nec sollicitudin lacus quam sed sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas interdum massa nulla, sed iaculis augue bibendum nec. Morbi elementum aliquam nunc, vitae elementum arcu bibendum non.
</section>
<footer>Footer content footer content footer content footer content footer content</footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

header,footer {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:20px;
    background:#222;
    color:#fff;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    /* position:fixed; */
    /* bottom:0px; */
    /* z-index:2; */
}
```

JavaScript

```
var footer_height,
    window_width = 0,
    $header = $('header'),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $footer = $('footer');

function checkFooter() {
    requestAnimationFrame(checkFooter);


    // Do calculation only if window width has changed.
    if(window_width !== window.innerWidth) {
        window_width = window.innerWidth;

        header_outer_height = $header.outerHeight();
        footer_outer_height = $footer.outerHeight();

        $content.css({
            'padding-top': header_outer_height,
            'padding-bottom': footer_outer_height
        });
        $footer.css('margin-top', footer_outer_height*-1);
    }
}

checkFooter();
```

**UPDATE**

as @Austin Brunkhorst pointed out, you can also just use the window.onresize event.

```
var footer_height,
    window_width = 0,
    $header = $('header'),
    $content = $('#content'),
    $footer = $('footer');

function checkFooter() {
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){

        window_width = window.innerWidth;

        header_outer_height = $header.outerHeight();
        footer_outer_height = $footer.outerHeight();

        $content.css({
            'padding-top': header_outer_height,
            'padding-bottom': footer_outer_height
        });
        $footer.css('margin-top', footer_outer_height*-1);


    });

}

window.addEventListener('resize', checkFooter);
```

Comment: Why would you update every frame when you you're able to on window resize?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst window.onresize would totally work fine, but I find requestAnimationFrame results in a smoother experience. window.onresize fires the event too often causing lag/stuttering.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Resizing is an event that doesn't frequently happen, and its responsiveness is not something worry about (unless it's blatantly blocking). Using the frame by frame approach consistently slows down the responsiveness of the website.

Comment: No it doesn't. That's the point of requestAnimationFrame it's lightweight. You can use onresize, just make sure you throttle it.

Comment: What do you mean by lightweight? I can guarantee you that `requestAnimationFrame` is called significantly more times than `window.onresize`. In fact, you might be a little insane if you think it's more lightweight. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AustinBrunkhorst/fbo6dqqb/)

Comment: Even though it is called it's not doing anything when the window.width doesn't change, so there's no harm done to performance. I have modified my answer to present the two options :)

Comment: The behaviour is exactly what I need! I'm just sorry that extra-javascript code is needed (I'd have hoped that a pure-css solution  should be possible). Anyway, +1 for the help and the effort!

Comment: @Giorgio If you know the header/footer heights are not going to change, the javascript is definitely not needed.

Comment: Unfortunately not. As you may have noticed, footer height increases when the window is narrow (because of the word-wrap), so I can't say that footer height is constant if I resize the window.

Comment: Well, it all depends on the design of your site. You can use media-queries to make adjustments. In the case of most of the sites I have made recently, once the window gets that narrow (mobile view), the footer disappears anyway and the content moves into a header dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got it. You want the footer to stay fixed at the bottom, except when the page shrinks... then the footer must be right bellow the content when it scrolls... right?

It requires a few tricks:

- Put the `footer` inside the `section`, for it will be controlling the size. You will need to change the `footer` from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`.
- Then, set the `section` to have a calculated `min-height`, so when the page is heigher it will expand to the bottom. Like:

`min-height: calc(100% - 60px - 70px); /* full height minus header and footer */`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utg0sbv1/10/

**EDIT**

Here's a non javascript, also css2 friendly solution:

You can set the content and footer to act like a table, then they'd be both relative to each other's height. It only requires that you wrap the content and footer to a div, that will be a `display: table;`. The content and footer will be `display: table-row`, and you will need to nest a child div inside each one of them to act as the `table-cell`.

Doing that, the content will always expand to the bottom, for the wrapper div is a full height, and the bottom will scroll down with the content when the page shrinks, no matter what is the footer's height!

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/utg0sbv1/12/

Comment: While `calc()` is perfect for this use case, I think it's better to use a JavaScript solution for compatibility.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I don't want the footer height to be fixed, but depending on footer content (I've added some notes to OP trying to clarify my goal). I'm wondering that JS should be the only solution.

Comment: Check the updated answer for another solution... No js

Answer (score 0):

may be you want this.. please try this....

```
#content
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
}
#push,#footer{height:100px;}
```

visit demo here: with more content: http://jsfiddle.net/gyvrk0vk/5/

with less content: http://jsfiddle.net/a0cu6qqc/2/

thank you..

Comment: Not exactly: your snippet forces footer to have a fixed height. In my case I would like footer height depends on its content. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

One solution is to set z-index of footer to -1, like so:

```
#content {
    background:#fff;
    padding-top:60px; /* fixed header compensation */
}

footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

If you want the footer to always stick to the bottom, here's a method I sometimes use on document resize:

```
windowHeight = $(window).height();
footerHeight = $("footer").height();

$("footer").css("margin-top", windowHeight - footerHeight);
```

Comment: Uhm... but in this case footer is hidden when I resize window. I would like footer to be displayed always under content. Thanks anyway.